# Cucumber step definition to ensure a list is created for me when I create a new account in a Rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

I'm fairly new to Cucumber and am having trouble with the final step of this scenario:

```
Scenario:
  Given I am on the sign up page
  When I create an account
  Then a new list should be created for my account at the same time
```

My models:

```
User has_one :list, dependent: :destroy
List belongs_to :user
```

My step definitions (I don't have anything for step 3)

```
Given(/^I am on the sign up page$/) do
  visit new_user_registration_path
end

When(/^I create an account$/) do
  fill_in 'Username', with: 'Test'
  fill_in 'Email', with: 'test@example.com'
  fill_in 'Password', with: 'abc12345'
  fill_in 'Password confirmation', with: 'abc12345'
  click_button 'Submit sign up'
end

Then(/^a new list should be created for me at the same time$/) do
  pending
end
```

How should my step definition look for the last step? I basically just want to ensure that after a new **User** is created, their associated **List** is created at the same time.

I've had a look at the pickle gem but I'm still quite new at this and am not really sure if there is a relevant step in pickle_steps.rb file.

Thanks!

Comment: please post the code you already have for that step.

Comment: Please post all of your step definitions.  The structure for the last step will depend on what you've done in the previous steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I posted this to r/bdd and someone's comment gave me a eureka moment:

With Cucumber, I shouldn't be using steps that relate to such a granular level of my program. The current scenario is looking at the app through the eyes of a **developer**, when it should be looking at it through the eyes of a **user**.

Here's a re-write that uses a better viewpoint:

```
Scenario:
  Given I am on the sign up page
  When I create an account
  Then I should be able to visit my list page
```

Cucumber should only be concerned with *whether* I can get there. It would be better at this point to drop down into something like RSpec to work out the details of *how* I get there (i.e. what the objects are doing rather than how they behave).

Comment: This is something I see all the time and remind myself to avoid. Instead of describing the UI (which is what you originally did), you want to describe the behaviour (which is what you ended up doing)